# CollapsingToolbarLayout contains ViewPager and a search box in it. How to prevent the search box only from collapsing,while ViewPager collapses

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my Fragment. It contains A `RelativeLayout` consisting of a `ViewPager` and an `EditText` aligned in top of `ViewPager`. When the user scrolls down the toolbar collapses. What i want is when it collapses I want to make only the `ViewPager` collapse but Edit Text remain un collapsed.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/loading_image"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/user"
                        android:text=""
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
               <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/user"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Search here"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/srch"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                               android:background="@drawable/search_border_grey"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/search_24"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="Button"/>
                </RelativeLayout> 



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/customgrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried adding a new layout below `AppBarLayout` and making it visible on collapsing of `Toolbar`, but its having a bad user experience since it causes the ui flicker. Is there solution for my requirement. All your responses are appreciated.

Comment: Use appbarlayout behaviour and change your view at end of appbarlayout at top.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH can u explain how to do it?

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872837/4824088) how can i change view in collapse will help you..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the user scrolls down the toolbar collapses. What i want is when
>   it collapses I want to make only the ViewPager collapse but Edit Text
>   remain un collapsed.

You have added `"scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` which means, it will close-exit the view when it collapsed.

In order to make `EditText` (Search) stay in there, I'd suggest adding the `EditText` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` as it's child then, anchoring it to the `AppBarLayout`. Just like when we anchor a `Fab` inside `CoordinatorLayout`.

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" // change it for your own porpuse
```

The other way I'd suggest (Not tested), would be adding :

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

To your `View` (`EditText` or Container of that) or, changing the flags to:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
```

In the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

---

It can however be done by handling `AppBarLayout` behavior to detect when it is collapsed or expended:

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset)
{
    if (offset == 0)
    {
        // Fully expanded
        // make your view visible or not collapsible here maybe?
    }
    else
    {
        // Not fully expanded or collapsed
    }
}
```

Check: [How can i determine that CollapsingToolbar is collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872653/how-can-i-determine-that-collapsingtoolbar-is-collapsed)

Comment: app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"  this one works, but when scrolls down the Grid View overlaps the EditText. How can i avoid the overlapping?

Comment: @visakhr Instead of `RelativeLayout`, add `NestedScrollView` and it will work fine.

Comment: It works, but when I add the EditText and GridView to NesterScrollView, Grid View not fitting the view, it shows only 1 row

Comment: **Don't add the `EditText` inside `NestedScrollView`**. Here `NestedScrollView` means **the content of the layout** which we show data on it. I meant by adding the `EditText` inside `CoordinatorLayout` was to where we put or add `Fab` Button. It should be under the `AppBarLayout` and as a child of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: okay, thats fine. GridView scrolls below EditText , but I couldn't set some padding between them. I have tried all combinations.Now the GridView Scroll end at the same line where EditText boarder is.

Comment: Is it possible to make the background color of layout containing EditText fill whewithn the toolbar color when it collapses?

Comment: Sorry. I don't get you, can you show me a screenshot or described by picture? Anyhow, this seems to be another question which should be described in another question.